# Showing content based on multiple dates

Tags: php, date

I am making a website for a store that wants to show the next open sunday dynamically based on date. I managed to make a script that does so but only tests one date. I want to test 10 dates without putting them in a database. This is my script.

```
<?

    $mydate = '2012-12-23';
    $curdate = date('Y-m-d');

    if($curdate == $mydate)
    {
        echo 'Vandaag';
    }
    elseif($curdate > $mydate)
    {
        echo '26 december';
    }
    elseif($curdate < $mydate)
    {
        echo '23 december';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Koopzondag niet ingeladen';
    }

?>
```

Comment: Do you have a database with open sundays?

Comment: Your unreachable `else` made me laugh

Comment: @zerkms, yet you include it in your answer ... ;)

Comment: @Bart Friederichs: when you're first to answer the question - you don't have time to think, but just copy and modify as fast as possible. Guilty :-(

Comment: Also, 26 december is not a sunday this year.

Comment: Besides making (some) people laugh for unreachable else statements and let them nitpicking over details, do you have an actual question?

Comment: There was an answer.. But it's deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php

$mydate = '2012-12-23';
echo date('d F', strtotime(getNextSunday($mydate)));

function getNextSunday($date) {
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    if (date('w', $timestamp) == 0) {
         $sunday = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp); // today
    }
    else {
        $sunday = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next Sunday', $timestamp)); // next sunday
    }
    return $sunday;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this imply that **every** Sunday is an "open Sunday" (if so, why even bother to create anything like this, just state that the shop is always open on Sundays)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of open Sundays in an array (when using a DB, the whole thing changes wildly, you will have the date functionalities of the DB at your disposal), you could do this:

```
$opensundays = array("2012-12-23", "2012-12-30", "2012-01-06");
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$r = "";

foreach ($opensundays as $idx=>$sunday) {
    if ($today == $sunday) {
        $r = "today is an open Sunday";
        break;
    } elseif ($today > $opensundays[$idx-1] && $today < $sunday) {
        $r = "next open Sunday is at ".$sunday;
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that this code has no boundary checks, it is just to show a concept.